# custom Rxjs filterNullish operator that takes array of values and changes each return type

Tags: rxjs

I have this custom operator that filters out nullish values (undefined and null) and also changes the return type to indicate that undefined or null is no longer a possible value.

Now I would like to expand this operator to not only take a single typed value but also support an array of typed values and filter if any of the arrays values are nullish and use the correct return type, such that it can be used in merge operator chain like `combineLatest`

```
export function filterNullish<T>(): UnaryFunction<Observable<T | null | undefined>, Observable<T>> {
  return pipe(filter(notNullish));
}

function notNullish<T>(value?: T | null | undefined): value is T {
  return value != null && value != undefined;
}
```

Current usage, this works:

```
  obs$ = this.store.select(selectSomething).pipe(
    // type of something is possibly null
    filterNullish(),
    // type of something is not null anymore
    map((something) => this.createOtherThing(something))
  );
```

Desired usage:

```
combineLatest([this.something$, this.otherthing$]).pipe(
  filterNullish(),
  // I want typescript to know EACH of the arrays elements types are not nullish anymore
  tap(([something, otherthing]) => {
    // do stuff knowing something and otherthing can not be nullish anymore
  })
)
```

Comment: I only want to pass when all values in the array param are not nullish. This question is about typescript which is statically typed. I think this should be possible, I just don't know the syntax

Comment: Ok, that's possible and plausible, sorry I misinterpreted your question, comment deleted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by constructing new array by filterNullish per element and passing tuple type:

```
export const filterNullishAll: <T>() => OperatorFunction<Array<any>, T> = <
  T
>() =>
  pipe(
    map((collection: any[]): T | null =>
      collection.every(notNullish) ? ([...collection] as T) : null
    ),
    filter(notNullish)
  );
```

Usage:

```
combineLatest([this.something$, this.otherthing$]).pipe(
  filterNullishAll<[SomethingType, OtherThingType]>(),
  tap(([something, otherthing]) => {
    // do stuff knowing something and otherthing can not be nullish anymore
  })
)
```

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I asked for clarification. In this solution you are removing entries from a tuple. If `this.something$` emits something nulish, it will be removed from the tuple, thus your _actual_ tuple will be `[otherthing, undefined]`. In your answer to my comment you implied that you wanted to filter out the whole tuple. This doesn't work, allthough you fooled typescript into believing it does.

Comment: I updated the operator to detect if any of the values in the array are nullish, then it returns nullish for the entire array of values, which gets filtered out after the map. Better?

Comment: Yes, that's probably what you intended to do originally. You can simplify it quite a bit. Should be enough to use `filter(arr => arr.every(notNullish))`